# rate of change question I need some explanation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I tried to solve them myself but couldn't; the questions look kind of different from the explanation first given. Any help on how to approach this problems would be much appreciated.
thank you a lot! 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you have $Q(t)=ke^{ct}$ and it takes $4$ years to triple, you are given $Q(4)=3Q(0)$.  Inserting the expression for $Q$ gives $ke^{4c}=3k$  Now solve this for $c$ and find the $t'$ such that $Q(t')=2Q(0)=2k$

Comment: Thank you Ross for the explanation.

Comment: C=Ln(3)/4 is it right?

Comment: as for t': Ke^ct' = 2K (the 3 K cancel out)==> e^[ln3/4]t' =2 ==> t' = 4ln2/ln3.is it right?

Comment: @Muath05:  you got it.  In your second comment you use C instead of c.  They are not the same.

Comment: sorry I meant c. thanks for noticing it. any idea about the first problem, please?

Comment: @Muath05:  Can you solve the left side without the $x$ term?  This is a standard homogeneous linear differential equation.  When you include the $x$, it becomes inhomogeneous.  The usual technique is to add any solution to the homogeneous equation to a particular solution to the inhomogeneous one.  There is a simple polynomial solution to the inhomogeneous one.